# Insights on SystemError: com_backpatch: offset too large

Tags: python

In python, `"SystemError: com_backpatch: offset too large"` is thrown when executing the code generated by the following:

```
f = open("test.py", "w")
f.write("def fn():\n   a =1000\n")
for a in xrange(3000):
   if a == 0:
      f.write("   if a == "+str(a)+": \n      print  "+str(a)+"\n")
   else:
      f.write("   elif a == "+str(a)+": \n      print  "+str(a)+"\n")



f.close()

import test
```

It is clear that if the length statement goes beyond a certain length, it throws this error.

Can someone give more insight into this error?

Comment: May I ask why do you need to generate the code like this?

Comment: We have a system where about 100s of rules need to applied. If any of the rules passes we process the transaction. These rules are maintained by different team in excel file than the developer. So we wrote a script to generate code like this.

Because of this error, We moved out of if..elif to function..if..return.

Answer (score 2):

Accourding to this: http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/pipermail/chimera-dev/2007/000404.html

> The Python bytecode compiler has a
>   limitation of a maximum of a 16 bit
>   offset in a jump instruction.  This
>   means that you don't want to have 64K
>   worth of characters in a single
>   conditional block of code

More details here: http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg72631.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hitting a python interpreter limit. It appears that the branch from the start of the if to the end is too far - probably because offset is limited to 16 bits. If you change the "elif" to "if" then the problem goes away.

You need to reduce the size of the "if/elif" chain.

HIH

...richie

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the solution for the problem, but not the internals of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JFYI, this script worked for me in a Debian Testing host with a 32bits userspace and kernel and Python 2.5.4.

```
$ ls -ln
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 270 2009-12-23 02:53 gentest.py
$ python gentest.py 
$ ls -ln
total 216
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000    270 2009-12-23 02:53 gentest.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 111799 2009-12-23 02:58 test.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  93299 2009-12-23 02:58 test.pyc
$ uname -srvmo
Linux 2.6.30-2-486 #1 Thu Dec 3 23:32:25 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
$ python --version
Python 2.5.4
```