# Error while adding new code after 3200 lines in Python using IDLE

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I have a python program which works fine and has 3200 lines of code. When I try to add new lines of code in it the following error appears:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python24\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1345, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\idlelib\ScriptBinding.py", line 142, in run_module_event
    code = self.checksyntax(filename)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\idlelib\ScriptBinding.py", line 101, in checksyntax
    return compile(source, filename, "exec")
SystemError: com_backpatch: offset too large
```

Comment: This answer might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1867203 (in short: you can not have more than 64k character in a single conditional block of code)

Comment: 64k characters in a conditional block is already _very_ large. Think about this "limitation" as a good occasion to refactor your code.